# Anatomically Correct Isitoq

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fauna, mythical-creatures

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)

This is the latest in a long series of questions I've asked on my fantasy world which contains many mythical and folkloric creatures. I won't link the other questions since at this stage the series has become huge.

The Isitoq is a creature from Inuit mythology. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F2A2HE4) describes it like so:

> The Isitoq . . . is covered in coarse hair. Its eyes are divided by a large mouth containing one tooth flanked on either side by a short one.

A Book of Creatures illustrates the Isitoq like this:

[image]

**What could this creature plausibly be, in terms of ancestry and relation to real animals?** A few criteria;

- Rely on the written account more than the picture, which is vulnerable to extra stuff added on by the artist
- I'd prefer if it didn't have a really early POD (e.g. it's a surviving dinosaur), because that would cause many other changes due to the Butterfly Effect
- It has to be something which could realistically exist in the Arctic, from a biogeographical standpoint. As a random example, penguins live in the Southern Hemisphere and have always lived there, so no penguins please.

If you can find other reliable accounts of the Isitoq's appearance **as told** in traditional folklore, you can use them as well.

Comment: Four eyeballs are not going to happen with terrestrial-vertebrate ancestry, I'm afraid...

Comment: The tooth arrangement depicted in the image is also going to be a nightmare to justify - both in terms of plausible ancestors (the side teeth are getting in the way of where the jaws would normally be), and in terms of how the creature is actually going to use them.

Comment: Are you sure it doeasn't mean that the two eyes are on either side of the mouth, and the smaller teeth on either side of the long one, as in eye-mouth-eye and tooth-TOOTH-tooth?

Comment: As to the eyes migrating downwards - it should be possible, but I can see no benefit to it. Also, where's the nose?

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Probably referring to a beak of some sort. I looked through the book the OP refers to from the preview on the Amazon page; the author appears to confuse sources. Seriously, "Ababil" referring to Arabic birds, sourced from _Korean_ mythology?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Well, there are four eyed fish (*Anableps* so.), so if the Isitoq was semi aquatic those would be beneficial. But the four eyes are just an addition by the illustrator. About the teeth, what if the side ones were tusks, in a dicynodont-like configuration. Again, the actual folkloric accounts day nothing about the position of the eyes.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "In Inuit mythology, Issitoq (also Isitoq) is a deity that punishes those who break taboos. He usually takes the form of a giant flying eye." Which is even harder to justify than the creature in this illustration or the one described. And that's even if we ignore the "flying" bit.

Comment: @nzaman That's exactly how I interpreted it.

Comment: No matter the mobility, just three teeth with one flanked by the other two... I can't see any possible use of them for the creature. Teeth need a hard surface to push against.

Comment: @John Dvorak maybe the extra pair of eyes are "fake" kinda like how peacocks (fan?) Looks like hundreds of eyes.

Comment: @JohnDvorak As I said, dicynodonts had an identical setup, except with a beak instead of the middle tooth: https://c8.alamy.com/comp/KW0NCR/placerias-dinosaur-head-placerias-was-a-herbivorous-dicynodont-dinosaur-KW0NCR.jpg

Comment: Does this have to be terrestrial? If not then some form of arthropod might be made to fit the bill.

Comment: @SealBoi That configuration does make sense, but I'm afraid it doesn't match the written description. The beak isn't inside a mouth, and I'd also argue that a beak counts as two teeth, not one. I'll allow the pair of decorative tusks though.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Not necessarily, although I'd prefer if it was greater than insect size.

Comment: @JohnDvorak The beak isn't necessary to the two side teeth anyway,  but even if it was, the beak *is* a mouth itself, and it's definitely not teeth, one or two.

Comment: All the Isitoqs I found in my search were flying eyeballs.

Comment: @Willk Mythical creatures often have extremely diverse depictions. Here are some sources which describe it as in my question: https://books.google.ie/books?id=4Cl0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=issitôq&source=bl&ots=AaxWJqt0Rf&sig=ACfU3U1Ps_WtV0TbXJ22GNHx-hpVFodODA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq3rCd3r7hAhWhTxUIHbJWBAoQ6AEwFHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=issitôq&f=false https://books.google.ie/books/about/Native_American_Myth_Legend.html?id=PrbeHAAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y https://www.google.com/amp/s/abookofcreatures.com/2019/02/15/issitoq/amp/ And then there was the one I quoted.

Comment: @JohnDvorak vertebrate animals with 3 eyeballs exist, iguanas for example,  and fish with 4 pupils exist too... So not quite unrealistic

Answer (score 4):

**They are hominids, displaced to the far north by Homo neanderthalis and then Homo sapients.**

I am reminded of Clark Ashton Smiths [Gnophkehs](https://monster.fandom.com/wiki/Gnophkeh) - hairy cannibal humanoids occupying the far north.  They are part of the Lovecraft mythos now and appear in one or two of his stories also.

The Isitoq have fur, as is helpful for cold climates.  These hominids, because of inbreeding / evolutionary bottleneck, have fused incisors.  Depicted are the front two fused in a member of our species.  The Isitoq have all 4 incisors fused, and these are flanked by the canines.  The molars are set farther back and out of sight.

Otherwise these relics have much in common with other hominids, including cooperation, culture and so on.  Of course they eat humans if necessity requires it.  So do humans when the go wendigo.  Starvation is always around the corner in the far north.

[image: fused incisors]
http://forum.dentalxp.com/case/details/treatment-options-fused-anterior-maxillary-teeth-number-8/2873

Answer (score 0):

The Isitoq could have evolved from a predatory jawed leech that increased in size to allow it to feed on larger prey. They may become more intelligent to find prey, and so also become endothermic. They would also evolve larger frontal eyes, due to needing to find prey at longer ranges. They may also need larger, more specialised teeth, such as a long tooth for killing prey and 2 shorter canines/molars that can tear up meat. Competition may increase, and so they might move into colder areas. To keep warm, they might start to wear the pelts of their prey, sticking them on with their slime.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for anatomically correctness not how did they evolve or why but still I will try to make them as most earthly possible.

**4 eyes**

The isitoq actually has only 2 **eyeballs** but 4 total eyes,  how?

Some people are born with more than one pupil in each eye, it is a dissease but people born with this rare condition are fertile which means that if it was to be to useful then it would eventually be selected over having one pupil per eyeball.

As it happened with the four eyed fish Anableps.

** vertical face splitting mouth**

Thats just orofacial cleft a not so rare mutation that happens in humans with a 0.02% chance and it causes the upper lip to to be split,  vertically and sometimes it can go even beyond and split the skull and fusing the nose and mouth into one hole.

The isitoq is just a more extreme variation of that dissease that, this can be  obtained by inbreeding.

Inbreeding in humans has happened many times in history and created some strange looking humans... Blue people exist because of Inbreeding so the idea that humans with that particular dissease taken to the extreme could evolve is not too far from reality.

**teeth to the side of the mouth**

This is easy, almost every person on earth ishas some teeth deformities and some the most extreme ones can result in teeth pointing forward and poking the lips or inward. You can either explain it as another teeth deformation that got worse through evolution, and this can actually happen and has happened.

Just look at warthogs, elephants and narvals.... They all started off with normal teeth and became freak animals.

Or you can explain them as being just exposed bones of the nose.

**Living in the artic**

This creature is perfect for that, it's short and fat which means it's really good at maintaining heat

Tall and skinny people lose heat easier, that's why Neanderthals where chonky and short kings. The fact that it they are covered in fur makes it even more realistic.